# Correct way to route container's traffic through wireguard without leakage, but UI access for LAN connections

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, docker, wireguard

I am currently trying to figure out the correct way to route "all" traffic of specific (**rootless**) docker containers through Wireguard while on the one hand preventing any leakage (if the connection/Wireguard fails - prevent any internet access) and on the other hand allow LAN connections (192.168.0.0/16) to access the UIs of the container's services.

The thing I tried first was to route the traffic through a [linuxserver/wireguard](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-wireguard) container with killswitch - this had some downsides:

- if the [wg-quick](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/wireguard-tools/wg-quick.8.en.html) config was faulty the wireguard connection was never established (+ killswitch IPTables rules never added), which lead to complete leakage of any traffic.
- local access of any of the services was only possible inside the container

To permit local traffic one could modify the IPTables rules and add routing rules (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-wireguard#maintaining-local-access-to-attached-services)) which sadly wasn't working for me. I furthermore tested rnd1783's procedure from [his recent question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/nuuvjg/iptables_in_wireguard_docker_killswitch/) which seemed to work, but like him, I am unsure whether that correctly solves my intentions (note the [single answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/nuuvjg/iptables_in_wireguard_docker_killswitch/h0zpphv/) by rcN9).

rcN9 seems to recommend using network namespaces (see e.g. [here](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/) or [here](https://sean.eulenberg.de/posts/forcing-docker-traffic-through-wireguard/)), but I am unsure whether that would be possible in a semi root (rootless docker/podman, prefer not to use root, but would if there is no other way) and container "style" environment.

What would be the best possible solution to my intentions:

- rootless containers (rootless docker, podman)
- prevent any leakage
- allow LAN access (to UIs)

This should be independent of any distribution, but I will mention it to be on the safe side:
looking for a solution which works with Debian.

**EDIT 1**:

- I could make use of a secondary (physical) network interface if that could help me.

Comment: First thing I'd try is to use a bridge network for those containers you want to have on the Wireguard network, and then use a specific container or the docker host to set up the Wireguard connection. Docker uses a ton of iptables rules, and messing with these without breaking something is very hard (and might still break between Docker versions).

Comment: Isn't that what rnd1783 is doing? He creates a (bridge) docker network and then uses linuxserver/wireguard to set up the Wireguard connection. @dirkt